# How to eliminate suspicious barcode (like 123456) data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

Here's some bar code data from a `pandas` database

```
737318  Sikat Botol Pigeon          4902508045506   75170
737379  Natur Manual Breast Pump    8850851860016   75170
738753  Sunlight                    1232131321313   75261
739287  Bodymist bodyshop           1122334455667   75296
739677  Bodymist ale                1234567890123   75367
```

I want to remove data that is suspicious (i.e. has too many repeated or successive digits) like  `1232131321313` , `1122334455667`, `1234567890123`, etc.  I am very tolerant of false negatives, but want to avoid false positives (bad bar codes) as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a job for pandas.

Comment: I guess I need some machine learning, but I has no clue

Comment: It appears to me that you may want to identify numbers that are highly 'non-random' or that are somehow different from the others in that column. You might be better to get preliminary advice from one of the statistical sources such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What action that your suggest, delete this question and post similar post in  stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: You should look into Long short-term memory (LSTM) - RNN using Keras or Tensorflow

Comment: Is impossible that using scikit-learn solution?

Comment: If you're searching for an excessive number of repeated or successive digits, I'd suggest taking a difference column-wise and doing a [Kolmogorov Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) against a Triangular distribution.

Comment: Good Idea, thanks for the suggestion, will try

Comment: Gimme a break with the "Too broad" close votes on a question with two fairly short algorithmic answers that both specifically answer the question..

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about repeated and successive digits, you can take `np.diff` of the digits and then compare against a triangular distribution using a [Kolmogorov Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).  The difference between successive digits for a random number should follow a triangular distribution between `-10` and `10`, with a maximum at `0`

```
import scipy.stats as stat
t = stat.triang(.5, loc = -10, scale = 20)
```

Turning the bar codes into an array:

```
a = np.array(list(map(list, map(str, a))), dtype = int)  # however you get `a` out of your dataframe
```

then build a mask with

```
np.array[stat.kstest(i, t.cdf).pvalue > .5 for i in np.diff(a, axis = 1)]
```

testing:

```
np.array([stat.kstest(j, t.cdf).pvalue > .5 for j in np.diff(np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 13)), axis = 1)]).sum()

Out: 720
```

You'll have about a 30% false negative rate, but a p-value threshold of `.5` should pretty much guarantee that the values you keep don't have too many successive or repeat digits.  If you want to really be sure you've eliminate anything suspicious, you may want to also  KS test the actual digits against  `stat.uniform(scale = 10)` (to eliminate `1213141516171` and similar).

Comment: If a `pandas` wizard could fix my data extraction (`a = np.array . . . `) algorithm to match the question I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step I would use the barcodes built in validation mechanism, the checksum. As your barcodes appear to be GTIN barcodes (specifically GTIN-13), you can use [this method](https://www.gs1.org/how-calculate-check-digit-manually):

```
>>> import math
>>> def CheckBarcode(s):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(s[:-1])):
            sum += int(s[i]) * ((i%2)*2+1)
        return math.ceil(sum/10)*10-sum == int(s[-1])

>>> CheckBarcode("4902508045506")
True
>>> CheckBarcode("8850851860016")
True
>>> CheckBarcode("1232131321313")
True
>>> CheckBarcode("1122334455667")
False
>>> CheckBarcode("1234567890123")
False
```

Comment: Excellent point.  You can probably crank down the p-value in my method to reduce false negatives if you first use the built-in error checking in the bar codes themselves.