# How to eliminate data that consist dual three consecutive numbers in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here's my data

```
id
123246512378
632746378456
378256364036
159204652855
327445634589
```

I want to make data that consist of data that consist dual three consecutive numbers like **123**2465**123**78, 3274**456|345**89 is reduced

```
id
632746378456
378256364036
159204652855
```

Comment: Does `1234` count as one set of consecutive numbers or two (`123` and `234`)?

Comment: no, I guess it definetely a new case

Comment: I'm not really sure what that answer means.

Comment: No, `1234` is new case, I have develop some cases, The original question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556587/how-to-eliminate-suspicious-barcode-like-123456-data, I to partitioning some cases

Comment: What's your tolerance for false negatives (i.e. throwing out good data)?

Comment: I highly tolerate false negatives instead of false positive

Answer (score 2):

First, turn `df.id` into a an array of single digit integers.

```
a = np.array(list(map(list, map(str, df.id))), dtype=int)
```

Then check to see if one digit is one less than the next digit... twice

```
first = a[:, :-2] == a[:, 1:-1] - 1
second = a[:, 1:-1] == a[:, 2:] - 1
```

Create a mask for when we have this happen more than once

```
mask = np.count_nonzero(first & second, axis=1) < 2
df[mask]

             id
1  632746378456
2  378256364036
3  159204652855
```

Comment: `map(str, df.id)` and not `df.id.astype(str)`? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is faster than @piRSquared as I'm not good enough with `pandas` to generate my own test data, but it seems like it should be:

```
def mask_cons(df):
    a = np.array(list(map(list, df.id.astype(str))), dtype = float) 
    # same as piRSquared, but float
    g_a = np.gradient(a, axis = 1)[:,1:-1] 
    # 3 consecutive values will give grad(a) = +/-1
    mask = (np.abs(g_a) == 1).sum(1) > 1
    # this assumes 4 consecutive values count as 2 instances of 3 consecutive values
    # otherwise more complicated methods are needed (probably @jit)
    return df[mask]
```